# want to show loading text before submitting using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i want to show loading text when click submit button and before the form submit. i tried this code.

```
<button type="button" @click="addCustomers" 
:disabled="disableSubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: 
right;" value="ADD CUSTOMER">{{customer.loading ? "Loading..." : "ADD 
CUSTOMER"}}</button>
```

after i add a loading object in data.

```
data(){
  return {
    loading: false,
  }
}
```

when i call to my click event function i add `"loading = true"` to display my loading text.

but this process not working. how can i show it. i don't want any spinner loading packages in vuejs. this is my click event function.

```
addCustomers(){
   customer.loading = true;
   axios.post(){
     ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `customer` data element is not mentioned in data object property, so your code  should be like :

```
 <button type="button" @click="addCustomers" 
 :disabled="disableSubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: 
 right;" value="ADD CUSTOMER">{{loading ? "Loading..." : "ADD 
 CUSTOMER"}}</button>
```

and in the methods:

```
 addCustomers(){
   this.loading = true;
    axios.post().then(res=>{
         this.loading=false;
       }).catch(err=>{
        //handle error
       })
  }
```

Comment: can i add this to a timeout

Comment: i think that you want something like i did in my edited answer